# How to delete everything after a certain character for whole column in df?

Tags: python, split

I have a df with one column (SKUID) where I want to remove all the characters that are not numerical. Here is an sample of the column:

[image: SKUID]

Essentially I want to remove the underscore and the letter for each row. I have tried using following code:

```
sku_data.split('_', 1)[0]
```

This gives me an error of 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do for number extraction:

```
sku_data.SKUID = sku_data.SKUID.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

**Note**: don't forget to add the `str` operator if  you want to perform string operations on a `DataFrame` column

Comment: This has not resolved my query, the columns still has the underscore and letter for each row. Is there are alternative code?

Comment: You have to assign the column, else the operation will be performed but not saved. Try my edited answer. As a recommendation if you still don't have a grasp of basic `pandas` operations and logic, try to study a bit more our you'll have many issues down the line